# IronPython: impossible to use pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ironpython

In the last two weeks I noticed that my ironpython installation is not able to use pip anymore, e.g.:

```
ipy.exe -m pip install <package>
```

the stacktrace is similar to the following:

```
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 376, in prepare_files
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._prepare_file(
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 551, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 728, in __init__
    self.parsed = html5lib.parse(
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 35, in parse
    if self.data.matchBytes(key):
  File "<path_to_bin>\bin\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 668, in matchBytes
    data = self[p:p + len(bytes)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

for any package, even trying to update pip itself.

I currently use ironpython 2.7.12, but it seems to fail the same way with the beta 3.4. I install pip with the ensurepip module, which corresponds to pip-19.2.3 setuptools-41.2.0